# Multiselect dynamic options based on first dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

In my website header I've coded four dropdowns, one is vehicle type, the next is vehicle make, the next is model and the last is vehicle engine size. The selected option for the first dropdown will set the options for the next dropdown and the next selected option will set the options for the next and so on.

I've managed to build and insert the four dropdowns based on code from an [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47815802/bootstrap-multiselect-dynamic-options-based-on-first-dropdown) I found but being the noob I am I have no idea where to insert the backend coding to make the search function properly. So where do I insert the first section of code (seen in the top answer of [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47815802/bootstrap-multiselect-dynamic-options-based-on-first-dropdown)) to make my dropdowns function dynamically?

I have tried inserting it just above the code for the dropdown boxes but this has not worked.

Edit: I should have said I'm creating this search element using Elementor's HTML widget in a premium theme. This widget allows you to build your own widgets by coding it within the Elementor editor. I'm unsure on which folder I should insert the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47815802/bootstrap-multiselect-dynamic-options-based-on-first-dropdown) into to get the widget to work dynamically.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: before the `</body>` close insert the JS code between `<script>` `</script>` tags